# Integral with respect to other parametrization.

Tags: differential-geometry, surface-integrals

I'm studying Do Carmo's differential geometry.

Let $Q$ be a compact region in $\mathbb{R^2}$ that is contained in a coordinate nbd $X : U \rightarrow S$, where $S$ is regular surface. I want to get that the integral
\begin{equation}
\int\int_Q |X_u \wedge X_v|dudv
\end{equation}
does not depend on the parametrization $X$.

Next is what the author demonstrate.

Let $\bar{X} : \bar{U} \rightarrow S$ be another parametrization with $X(Q) \subset \bar{X}(\bar{U})$ and set $\bar{Q} = \bar{X}^{-1}(X(Q))$. Let $\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(\bar{u},\bar{v})}$ be the Jacobian of the change of parameters $h=X^{-1}• \bar{X}$. Then
\begin{equation}
\int\int_{\bar{Q}} |\bar{X}_{\bar{u}} \wedge \bar{X}_{\bar{v}}|d\bar{u}d\bar{v} 
\\
=\int\int_{\bar{Q}} |X_u \wedge X_v| | \frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(\bar{u},\bar{v})} | d\bar{u}d\bar{v} \\
=\int\int_Q |X_u \wedge X_v|dudv
\end{equation}

I can't catch the first equality. Please help. I'm so confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should carefully think about change of coordinates. The partial derivatives of $\bar{X}$ and $X$ are related via the change of parameters diffeomorphism. We have to first **assume** that the compact $Q\subset U$ lies entirely within the intersection $U\cap X^{-1}(\bar{X}(\bar{U}))$, or more visually, that the compact set $X^{-1}(Q)$ lies in the common image of both parametrizations.

Then, I will avoid using explicit coordinates. Let $X_1,X_2:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be the partial derivatives of the first parametrization, and let $\bar{X}_1,\bar{X}_2:\bar{U}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be the partial derivatives of the other parametrization. Recall that by the very definition of regular surface, the map

$$X^{-1}\circ \bar{X}:\underbrace{\bar{U}\cap \bar{X}^{-1}(U)}_{\bar{G}}\rightarrow \underbrace{U\cap\bar{X}^{-1}(U)}_G$$

is a diffeomorphism between open sets of $\mathbb{R}^2$. The chain rule tells us therefore that $\bar{X}|_{\bar{G}} = X|_{G} \circ (X^{-1}\circ \bar{X})$ has partial derivatives (dropping the restriction $|_G$ to the corresponding open subsets)

$$
\bar{X}_1 = X_1 \cdot \partial_1(X^{-1}\circ \bar{X})^1 + X_2 \cdot \partial_1 (X^{-1}\circ \bar{X})^2
$$
$$
\bar{X}_2 = X_1 \cdot \partial_2(X^{-1}\circ \bar{X})^1 + X_2 \cdot \partial_2 (X^{-1}\circ \bar{X})^2
$$

Here $\partial_i (X^{-1}\circ \bar{X})^j$ is the function that denotes the i-th partial derivative of the j-th component of the change of coordinates map. Now we compute the vector product of the two partial derivatives above expanding from the right-hand-side, taking into account that $X_1\times X_1 = 0 = X_2\times X_2$ and $X_2\times X_1 = - X_1\times X_2$:
$$
\bar{X}_1\times \bar{X}_2=\left(\partial_1(X^{-1}\circ \bar{X})^1 \cdot \partial_2(X^{-1}\circ \bar{X})^2 - \partial_2(X^{-1}\circ \bar{X})^1 \cdot \partial_2 (X^{-1}\circ \bar{X})^1\right)X_1\times X_2
= \det (D(X^{-1}\circ \bar{X})) \cdot X_1\times X_2
$$
where we have carefully identified the determinant of the Jacobian of the change of coordinates map. Then

$$
\|\bar{X}_1\times \bar{X}_2\| = |\det(D(X^{-1}\circ \bar{X}))| \cdot \|X_1\times X_2\| \circ (X^{-1}\circ \bar{X})\qquad (\star)
$$

I am here being pedantic ad nauseam writting explicitly every composition. Any person already accustomed to change of variables would simply write

$$
\|\bar{X}_1\times \bar{X}_2\| = |\det(D(X^{-1}\circ \bar{X}))| \cdot \|X_1\times X_2\|
$$

Thus we get from the [change of variables theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables) for $\psi = X^{-1}\circ \bar{X}$, $Q=\psi(\bar{Q})$

$$\int_{Q=\psi(\bar{Q})} \|{X}_1 \times {X}_2\| d{u}d{v} =
\int_{\bar{Q}} \|X_1\times X_2\| \circ (X^{-1}\circ \bar{X}) \cdot |\det(D\psi)|d\bar{u}d\bar{v}
\overset{\star}{=}
$$
$$
= \int_{\bar{Q}} \frac{1}{|\det(D\psi)|} \|\bar{X}_1\times \bar{X}_2\| |\det(D\psi)| d\bar{u}d\bar{v} =\int_{\bar{Q}} \|\bar{X}_1\times \bar{X}_2\| d\bar{u}d\bar{v}
$$

Comment: I appreciate your devote.. Thank you.